# Javascript: onclick handler unable to get 'value' attribute from <a> tag

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my html document

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
         {% for type in types %}
             <li>
                 <a value="{{ type.name }}" onclick="addType(this)" >{{ type.name }}</a>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

A Django-template language loop provides the values for the < a > tags, and I have verified that {{ type.name }} != None

Yet the following function only prints out the 'raw html' for the tag.

```
function addType(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.value);

}
```

The subsequent console.log of e.value returns an undefined. (Even when I replace the Django variable with something like 'IHaveaValue')

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: anchors really do not have values, so you really should be using data attributes.

Comment: According to W3C validator: The value attribute does not exist for the "a" tag. You should use: `data-value`. The validator says: *Attribute value not allowed on element a at this point.*

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez you can (generally) add any _attribute_ you want in the HTML.  That doesn't mean that a corresponding _property_ will exist.

Comment: @Alnitak I know. My comment is only related to the correct way to write HTML5 according to W3C. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the text value of the anchor? If so the `innerHTML` will give you that.

```js
function addType(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.innerHTML);

}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
         {% for type in types %}
             <li>
                 <a value="{{ type.name }}" onclick="addType(this)" >{{ type.name }}</a>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

[As you can see from their definition, anchors do not have a "value" **property**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)  You can instead use your own data **attribute**, for instance like this :

```
<a data-val="{{ type.name }}" onclick="addType(this)" >{{ type.name }}</a>
```

then

```
 console.log(e.getAttribute('data-val'));
```

To be more complete, properties are inherent to the element, whereas attributes can be defined by user. In fact, although you can't access e.value (ie the property) for an anchor, you could access the value "attribute" if you defined it, using e.getAttribute('value'). But to avoid confusion, creating a custom "data attribute" is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: please refer to a canonical reference, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a, not W3Schools

Comment: Huh, It never occurred to me that tags do not share all attributes. Thanks for the response!